# Apache Solr Unable to Store Nested JSON data

Tags: java, json, apache, solr, solr6

i am trying to load the following data into an existing SOLR(6.6) core using the document upload section

```
   {
    "id": "1234",
    "nationality":"India",
    "phonenumber":"232323",
    "personname":"babu rao",
    "paid":"credi card",
    "status":"success",
    "access" :[
      {"port":"port1","gate":"Gate1"}
    ],
    "approved_by":[
      {"name":"appr1","date":"2006-11-30"},
      {"name":"appr2","date":"2006-11-30"}
    ]
  }
```

My Schema for this item is

```
 <field name="created_date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="passType" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="duration" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="nationality" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="phonenumber" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="personname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="paid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="passamount" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="status" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="approved_by" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> 
 <field name="approved_by.name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="approved_by.date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="access" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> 
 <field name="access.port" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="access.gate" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I get the following error

```
Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START at [177], 
field=access
```

Request your help to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

**_childDocuments_** key need to indicate the nested documents in JSON. I have updated the document now it will be Indexed.

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "nationality":"India",
    "phonenumber":"232323",
    "personname":"babu rao",
    "paid":"credi card",
    "status":"success",
    "_childDocuments_" :[
      {"id":456,"port":"port1","gate":"Gate1"},
      {"id":786,"name":"appr1","date":"2006-11-30"},
      {"id":232,"name":"appr2","date":"2006-11-30"}
    ]
  }
```

Also You need to change the schema.xml.
[**Schema.xml**]

```
<field name="created_date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="passType" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="duration" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="nationality" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="phonenumber" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="personname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="paid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="passamount" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="status" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="port" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="gate" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

For More Information you can check this article by Yonik :-
http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/